# Prevent splash screen from being shown when using a script?

Tags: python

I'm writing a Python script that creates a Blender scene; I'm running it from the command line with `blender -P script.py`. However, the splash screen always appears and it's really annoying. Is there something I can do from the script that prevents the splash screen from showing up for just that invocation of Blender? Note that I do *not* want to change the global preference.

The tooltip over the user preferences splash screen setting recommends `bpy.types.UserPreferencesView.show_splash`, but changing this from my script doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Is there a reason why you invoke your script via command line in window-mode? You would typically run a script via a button in the UI if you work in Blender, or run a script via command line with blender in background mode (no window, usually for rendering).

Comment: I'm not working in Blender. I'm just using it to look at the results of another tool.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The attribute to change is not in `UserPreferencesView` *type*, but in that class' *instance*. The right instance to modify, currently used viewing data preferences, is the [`view`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_3/bpy.types.UserPreferences.html#bpy.types.UserPreferences.view) attribute of [`bpy.context.user_preferences`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_3/bpy.types.Context.html#bpy.types.Context.user_preferences):

```
import bpy

bpy.context.user_preferences.view.show_splash = False
```

Comment: 2.8: `bpy.context.preferences.view.show_splash = False`

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer was correct before, but now the interface has changed.

#### After Blender 2.80

```
import bpy

bpy.context.preferences.view.show_splash = False
```

#### Before Blender 2.80

```
import bpy

bpy.context.user_preferences.view.show_splash = False
```